# magento 2 add coupon for guest with api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, coupon

I use magento 2.1.8 and when i add coupon by API i get this error

```
{"message":"No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue","parameters":{"fieldName":"cartId","fieldValue":null}
```

this is my url `/rest/V1/guest-carts/65521/coupons/888` and i use PUT for this request. 
can show me one example or good documents with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the route of guest cart coupons API is `<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/coupons/:couponCode" method="PUT">`

So the request url should be: http://{magento_url}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/{quote_masked_id}/coupons/888

with {magento_url} is your Magento Store Url
and {quote_masked_id} is masked_is that was recored in quote_id_mask table:

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue

Regards